# TCP: Почему клиент не может узнать, если сервер вообще не выполнил accept()?

Tags: c#, c++, сокет, tcp, tcp-ip

Пишу такой сервер:

```
var tcp = new TcpListener();
tcp.Start(IP, port);

//Далее вообще-то следует код, который по идее должен Accept()ить клиента,
//но, допустим, я допускаю баг в коде сервера, в результате у меня на сервере происходит только запуск сервера
//то есть после Start() ничего нет
```

Тем временем, клиент вот такой:

```
var tcp = new TcpClient();
try 
{
  tcp.Connect(ip, port);
}
catch (Exception ex) // ----- Check #1
{
  log("Can't connect");
  return;
}
log("Connected");

//Sending first HeartBeat
var buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("heartbeat");
tcp.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);

//Loop for reading response for HeartBeat and for another messages
while (true)
{
  var buf = new byte[10];

  int nReaden = -1;
  try 
  {
    nReaden = tcp.GetStream().Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
  }
  catch (Exception ex) // ----- Check #2
  {
    log("Can't read because connection closed by server / Ethernet cable unplugged / Wi-Fi disconnected / etc");
    return;
  }

  log(nReaden + ": " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf));
  //TODO Sending next HeartBeat
}
```

Я пробую это в работе.
Запускаю сервер.
Запускаю клиент - вижу в логе "Connected" и то что ни Check #1 ни Check #2 не срабатывают, во всяком случае я жду несколько минут и Check #2 так и не срабатывает

Смотрю Wireshark на клиенте - и вижу, что все работает так, как будто бы на сервере был accept().
То есть:
- при client.Connect сервер возвращает ACK, соответственно на клиенте Check #1 не срабатывает
- при client.Write сервер тоже возвращает ACK, соответственно на клиенте Check #2 тоже не срабатывает
- клиент думает, что все в порядке.

Но ведь на сервере нет accept(), поэтому по факту сервер не получает сообщение.

Конечно, эта вымышленная ситуация с багом на сервере - это скорее академический вопрос, чем практический.

1) Но все же интересно - почему создатели TCP сделали именно так, ведь ИМХО это неверное решение?
Они могли бы сделать так, чтобы ACK об успешном SYN приходил на клиент **только** после того, как сервер произведет успешный accept() данного клиента.
Почему не сделали?

2) Можно ли как-то исправить "проблему" штатными средствами TCP? *(то есть не прикручивая клиенту свой кастомный таймаут-таймер, который будет запускаться после Write() и ждать Read() в течение NNNN мсек, и если его нет, то выбрасывать Exception)*?
Именно способ со своим таймаутом кажется мне самым надежным во всех отношениях (включая психологическую надежность), но он запутанный и кривой, вряд ли его можно рекомендовать.

Comment: *Но ведь на сервере нет accept(), поэтому по факту сервер не получает сообщение.* - это зависит от семантики accept, пока я не видел нигде обещания, что accept участвует в three-way handshake. Он может тпросто *передавать* уже существующий коннект.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2097730/2908793

Comment: @Etki Передавать из ядра системы в мое приложение?

Comment: Вроде того. Выдавать вам интерфейс для коммуникации, не производя никаких сетевых действий.

Comment: @Etki Так и понял, но вернемся к вопросу - почему так сделано? Why it designed so? Есть вам что сказать по этому поводу? Представьте, если бы вы создавали свой транспортный протокол для использования внутри компании. При этом, в отличие от создателей TCP, у вас есть опыт, доказывающий, что в TCP есть конкретные несовершенства, от которых в своем протоколе лучше отказаться. И вот это вот - одно из них. Согласны? Если нет - можете поспорить?

Comment: Не согласен. Если бы мы добавили возможность участвовать в three-way хендшейке, все равно пришлось бы добавить ожидание его окончания, с чем было бы сложно работать; кроме того, в каком-нибудь eventloop'e до accept'а приложение дойдет не сразу, и к этому времени весьма логично поднакопить в буфере то, что клиент собирался отправить.

Comment: @Etki eventloop с неблокирующими вызовами я не пишу. Какой в этом смысл? Проще на сервере на каждый клиент сделать по потоку, то есть первый поток acceptит и создает второй, третий, четвертый, на каждого клиента свой поток. А чтобы на сервере можно было что-то отправить тому же клиенту в новом (еще одном) потоке и при этом write(payload) не вызывалось параллельно write(heartbeat) - я использую семафоры.

Comment: вы не пишете, другие пишут. никто не гарантирует, что ваш код вообще доберется до обработки нового подключения в ближайшие N минут даже при использовании потоков. вы же сейчас де-факто критикуете архитектуру операционной системы за то, что она не идеально удовлетворяет вашему единичному случаю.

Comment: @Etki могла бы удовлетворять, ну те же sockopt'ы не зря же придумали, по умолчанию пусть бы было так, но можно было настроить.

Comment: @KG, Вы хотите, чтобы `connect` возвращал управление в клиенте только когода сервер получил сокет, вызвав `accept`? Если да, то это просто handshake уже прикладного протокола. Напишите свои функции `Accept`, которая получив сокет будет писать туда приветствие и `Connect`, которая после `connect` будет считывать приветствие и только после чтения возвращаться в код пользователя.

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения реализации TCP в ОС, вы готовы к принятию соединений (к `accept`) в тот момент, как вызвали `listen`, что у вас и происходит "за кадром" в `tcp.Start(IP, port);`.

А вызов `accept` всего лишь возвращает в прикладную программу новый сокет, ассоциированный с уже совершенным в ОС соединением.

В этом плане мы можем рассматривать поведение `accept` аналогично `read`, с той разницей, что `read` возвращает данные, посланные клиентом, а `accept` "служебную информацию" (новое соединение с заданным портом).